# .child() returns 2nd level items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well i think .child() function is my problem... But im not sure about this.

I have this in html

```
<div class="tabs" data-name="1st level tabs">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">1st level link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="content">
        <li>
        1st TEXT
        <div class="tabs" data-name="2st level tabs">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">2nd level link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2nd level link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="content">

            </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>1st TEXT</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

One element with class "tabs" inside another... ok; in JS:

```
$(function($) {
    var Tabs = function(element,options){
        self = this;
        self.$element = element;


        self.testdrive = function (){
            console.log(self.$element.attr("data-name"));
        }

        self.$element.children(".nav").children("li").children("a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //Returns EVER 2nd level
            self.testdrive();
            //Triggering directly a Tabs instance returns EVER 2nd level
            $(this).closest(".tabs").data("test.tabs").testdrive();
        });

    }
    //JQuery plugin
    $.fn.tabs = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data  = $this.data('test.tabs');
            //Creating only one instance of Tabs
            if(!data){
                data = new Tabs($this);
                $this.data('test.tabs',data);
            }
        });
    }
    //Adding tabs plugin to all ".tabs"
    $(function() {
        $('.tabs').each(function(){
            $(this).tabs();
        });
    });
}( jQuery ));
```

When $(element).tabs() called, creates a instance of function Tabs inside a data attribute test.tabs. If test.tabs has been defined only uses an old instance to preserve it.

To test it, i created a function called testdrive, to print in console "data-name" attribute when .tabs>.nav>li>a has been clicked.

The code works but, in console i receive "2st level tabs" if i clicked on 1st level item.
Is a problem with child() function? Something wrong in my code?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the variable declaration for `self`, since you haven't used `var` to declare it is created in the global context. So

```
var self = this;
```

also you are setting the data using key `test.tabs`, but is reading it using key `simple.tabs`

```
$(this).closest(".tabs").data("test.tabs").testdrive();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Z8UN/)

Also I think you can use `self.$element.find(" > .nav > li > a").click(function (e) {});` to register the click handler

Comment: That was a mistake typing (simple.tabs/test.tabs) im fixed it, and im tested with your selector but same thing, ever says "2nd..."

Comment: @StefanLuv try the updated one http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Z8UN/5/ - try the fiddle

Comment: Damn, i forgot "var"... That fixed it, i really apreciated it, tanks a lot